Naming convention for normal/quasinormal modes.
A solution $u \equiv u(t,\vec{x})$ to a (linear?) PDE of the form
$$u(t,\vec{x}) = e^{i \omega t} p(\vec{x})$$
for some spatial profile $p$ is called

Normal mode if $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$

Quasinormal mode if $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$

Static if $\omega = 0$


QUESTION:
Is there a name for the case:

$\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\operatorname{Re} \omega = 0$

Is there something like an Anormal mode?
